# How to remove "catalog" from Ubercart Catalog View URL

Tags: 7, views, ubercart

I need to remove the word "catalog" from the URL when viewing a category of products. I am using the stock uc_catalog view. Its Page (Table) display has a URL of "/_catalog". What can I change so that the word catalog will be completely excluded?

For example, I'd like my category URLs to be like so:

> mysite.com/shirts
>
> mysite.com/pants

instead of:

> mysite.com/catalog/shirts
>
> mysite.com/catalog/pants

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Logical we can't change the way the catalog link generation of Ubercart. The format must be catalog/term_id (with default way) and catalog/term_name (With pathauto module). For me the only thing we can deal with that is creating the URL Aliases manually.